# Angular directive template switch

Tags: angularjs, templates

I want to make a directive with a switch between template and templateUrl. I'll write a little example.

HTML:

```
<my-menu template-url='/admin/my-template'> </my-menu>
```

JS:

```
angular
    .module('MyModule', [])
    .directive('myMenu', function($compile){
        var x = false;
        var y = function(scope, element){
            return (element.templateUrl) : false ? '<div>You should give template-url</div>'
        }
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: y,
            templateUrl: '/admin/my-template'(i hard coded inhere) 
        }
    })
```

If i use "template: x" it works. template will be false and i get my templateUrl, but with a simple function that will return false i get an error:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt?p0=myMenu&p1=

Can i do something in this case? I really want to evaluate my directive scopes before. Thx and sorry for not having a plunker

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Basically if i provide a template-url to my directive i want to have templateUrl with it and if i don't provide a template-url i want to show that div. But template: function(){return false} it's not working.